How to get OpenVPN's remote peer external (real) IP address?
When connecting to an OpenVPN server I use an FQDN that may resolve into multiple IP addresses yet only one of them is chosen/used as long as the VPN session is alive.
How can I get it?
ifconfig, route, ip a, ip l, ip r don't have it.
journalctl -b | grep "UDPv4 link remote" contains it but I don't want to use/parse journalctl.
I'm connecting using NetworkManager's OpenVPN plugin.

Does the address you mean appear in the output of nmcli connection show <name of VPN connection>?

This IP address is not present in this output. It's only shown as a FQDN as VPN.GATEWAY. I need to get an actual IP address.

If the IP address is not in the output of nmcli connection show, then as far as I can tell the best source would be inspecting the established TCP connections: port 1194 for OpenVPN, e.g. via ss --tcp --ipv4 -o state ESTABLISHED dport = :openvpn; the output of ss can be massaged (see man ss).
There's a UDP mode for OpenVPN, but I think there's a control link that's always there going through TCP. If that's not the case, well, you already know a solution (that's not great, I agree) with journalctl.

Thanks a ton! I've created a feature request: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/1614
